# Change multi dimension numeric array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Basicly I've got this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 15
            [username] => test user 1
            [user_email] => test1@mail.com
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 19
            [username] => test user 2
            [user_email] => test2@mail.com
        )
)
```

And I would like to use the `user_id` as array key. So it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [username] => test user 1
            [user_email] => test1@mail.com
        )
    [19] => Array
        (
            [username] => test user 2
            [user_email] => test2@mail.com
        )
)
```

I can accomplish that by using the following code.

```
<?php
$newArray = array();
foreach( $array as $data ) {
    $newArray[ $data['user_id'] ] = array(
        'username'=> $data['username'],
        'user_email' => $data['user_email'] );
}
?>
```

But when there are more parameters, the amount of lines is huge. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Instead of copying each element separately you can keep the whole array and just `unset()` the `user_id` element.

Comment: `$newArray[ $data['user_id'] ] = $data`?

Comment: @arkascha, that doesn't change the key of the array.

Comment: @arkascha also my initial thought. The right way to do it in this case!

Comment: @LinkinTED I added it as an answer below...

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. That is what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep the array and `unset()` the `user_id`:

```
<?php
$newArray = array();
foreach( $array as $data ) {
    $newArray[ $data['user_id'] ] = $data;
    unset($newArray[$data['user_id']]['user_id']);

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, once again I'm overthinking the problem.